# No Content-Security-Policy meta tag found error

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I am building my application in ionic framework. I have installed cordova whitelist plugin and following is my config.xml but I still get the error

```
I/chromium( 2446): [INFO:CONSOLE(173)] "No Content-Security-Policy meta tag found. 
Please add one when using the cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin.", source: 
file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-console/www/console-via-logger.js (173)
```

My config.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<widget id="com.ionicframework.public279104" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
  <name>public</name>
  <description>
        An Ionic Framework and Cordova project.
    </description>
  <author email="hi@ionicframework" href="http://ionicframework.com/">
      Ionic Framework Team
    </author>
  <content src="index.html"/>
  <!-- <allow-navigation href="*" /> -->
  <allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
  <allow-navigation href="https://*/*" />
  <allow-navigation href="data:*" />
  <allow-intent href="*" />
  <access origin="*"/>
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16"/>
  <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000"/>
  <feature name="StatusBar">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVStatusBar" onload="true"/>
  </feature>
  <platform name="android">
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" density="ldpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" density="mdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" density="hdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" density="xhdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxhdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" density="land-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" density="land-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" density="land-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xxxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxxhdpi"/>
  </platform>
</widget>
```

Why is this happening? My app also crashed frequently with message "your app stopped workign unfortunately"

Comment: go for https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whitelist can allow/block network requests to/from certain protocols (e.g., HTTP/HTTPS) from the WebView which Cordova provides (`UIWebView` for iOS and `WebView` for Android).

However, it cannot filter all types of requests (`<video>`, `<media>`, sockets as an example), so the `Content-Security-Policy` is required to filter this.

This is controlled via a meta tag in your HTML file(s):

```
<!-- Good default declaration:
    * gap: is required only on iOS (when using UIWebView) and is needed for JS->native communication
    * https://ssl.gstatic.com is required only on Android and is needed for TalkBack to function properly
    * Disables use of eval() and inline scripts in order to mitigate risk of XSS vulnerabilities. To change this:
        * Enable inline JS: add 'unsafe-inline' to default-src
        * Enable eval(): add 'unsafe-eval' to default-src
-->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">

<!-- Allow requests to foo.com -->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' foo.com">

<!-- Enable all requests, inline styles, and eval() -->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">

<!-- Allow XHRs via https only -->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' https:">

<!-- Allow iframe to https://cordova.apache.org/ -->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; frame-src 'self' https://cordova.apache.org">
```

More info: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist.

**Edit:** as for your question on why your app keeps crashing, I cannot determine why with the information provided so I will need a little more info.

It isn't related to the `Content-Security-Policy` though.

Maybe some Android/iOS logs would help.